# How to compute value based on the result from previous row in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to compute a new column from in a data frame that is taking value for computation from previous row, which was just computed. For example, if the formula is x_i = x_(i-1)*2 and x_0 = 1, then we would have something like this:

```
df$x
1
2
4
8
16
```

I know I could use a loop to do the calculation, but is there anything handy that can do the same trick? Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi @CaptainSegFault if any of the answers below worked for you, consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know the answer worked for you and that the issue should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Reduce` function in base R:

```
  Reduce("*",c(1,rep(2,6)),accumulate = T)
  1  2  4  8 16 32 64
```

Comment: `2^0:6` will solve the problem or even `cumprod(c(1, rep(2, 6)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function (*although I'm not sure what's wrong with a simple loop*)

#### Data

```
 df <- data.frame(x=1)
```

#### Function

```
 special <- function(x,count,end) { 
                 if (count < end) {
                     x <- c(x, tail(x,1)*2)
                     special(x, count+1, end)
                 } else {
                     return(x)
                 }
            }
```

#### Output

```
 special(df$x, 1, 5)
 # 1  2  4  8 16
```

Comment: Loop works, it's just I got millions of rows so that using loop is extremely slow.